# Pickle EOF error while loading object

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I saved a model object as follows:

```
with open('bestModel_smv_3class_version2data.pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(jpsa_svm_3class.g_cv.best_estimator_,f)
```

Now when I try to load it, it gives an error

```
with open('bestModel_smv_3class_version2data.pickle','rb') as f:
    svm_bestModel=pickle.load(f)
```

Error:

```
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-df8734c64828> in <module>()
      8 
      9 with open('bestModel_smv_3class_version2data.pickle','rb') as f:
---> 10     svm_bestModel=pickle.load(f)

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Maybe double-check somehow if that file is ok. I would do it again, using some smaller and fast-fitted model. Maybe something went wrong last time (hdd-space, sys-memory, some other crash). And just to be sure: you are not pickling/unpickling on different versions/systems, right?

Answer (score 0):

`pickle` can't handle `sklearn` models as they contain `numpy` arrays. Use `joblib.dump` instead, it's similar but they've special cased saving / loading large `numpy` arrays.

https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/persistence.html

Comment: But isn't pickle able to store python class objects? What if my class object has an attribute which is sklearn model? Pls see this question I asked and haven't been able to get an answer yet. 

Problem is my model and class objects are pickled already. I need to load them now to use it further

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272487/loading-python-class-object-as-pickle-error

Comment: yes `python` class objects, `numpy` uses data representations that are not exactly `python` class objects but efficiently stored data arrays in `C` or `Fortran` order. It doesn't matter if you've encapsulated those in a `python` class  `pickle` has to be able to de/serialise everything, not just the object container. I'm sorry to be the bringer of bad news, but you need to train your models again and persist them using `joblib` the `pickle` files are of no use.

Comment: I am not sure you got the link in the previous comment. As you see, it is able to load the pickle class. Then using the loaded pickle class I can retrieve the attribute there. But the issue is that loading code is only working in the notebook where the model was trained. Other notebook trying to load the class is giving the error as shown in the lin

Comment: I don't know what's going on in your previous question, maybe the model wasn't fitter and thus did not contain the numpy arrays, but I can tell you from personal experience that `pickle` can not handle fitted `sklearn` models, use `joblib` instead. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: The [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) indicate pickle is fine (which would not surprise me as they probably defined special pickle-behaviour for all their classes, including using numpy's own array-pickle defs) and joblib is just more specialized for performance. The official example is using vanilla pickle too.

Comment: And skimming over the sources: all model-serialization tests are using pickle!